# Wordpress Failure - Theme My Login (logout)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just uploaded my wordpress site to a live server. When I try and logout it takes me to a 'Wordpress Failure' page that asks me if I really want to logout. I'm using the theme my login plugin.

I've tried reinstalling the plugin, changing the permalinks, etc. I still can't put my finger on what the problem is..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. I figured out that I just needed to use the wordpress logout function. That solved my problem. Thanks!

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```